# How to package laravel app using composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've developed a Laravel app which I want to package so that it can be deployed on any server. But I don't want to take the entire dump, instead share just the developed controllers, models, views, assets etc and automate the install process using composer. I tried searching everywhere, but all I got is how to deploy libraries and packages in existing laravel installation.

Requirement is as follows:

1. Don't want to export entire laravel dump.
2. Just take out the developed files and package them.
3. Create a composer.json file which will install the required dependencies such as latest laravel framework and related dependencies.
4. Copy the packaged controllers, models, views, assets to respective folders of laravel framekwork.
5. Make the installation of entire app including laravel framework as easy as possible.

Can anyone help on how to achieve this?

Comment: I also would like to know

Comment: Not possible (no tool exist that conforms to your requirements); you need to research how to automate this; use git as much as possible; as well as composer.json (list all requirements; pecl included). Learn ansible or chef to provision server for you or try forge (paid solution).